# How do Android Communicate with Storage or External Storage?

Tags: file-system

I Wants to know that how the android os is communicating with the storage devices, as because I have two USB Devices from same vendor (ScanDisk) and of equal size (8 GB) and having same File System (FAT32).

Scenario is, I am trying to use those USB Devices using OTG Cable With my MOTO X Play. Lets say USB-A is working fine but not USB-B. Even i Tried to format them using Windows OS to NTFS / FAT32, but still the result is same.

In next attempt I made copy of default folder / directory that usually created by android system to external storage to both USB's, then the Scenario get reversed. with FAT32 / NTFS USB-B works fine but not USB-A.

Surprised? I'm too but I wants to find the reason. Both USB are working fine with other OS like Windows / Linux(Desktop version) as I checked already.

Comment: Do you realise that NTFS and FAT32 are not the same thing? With that in mind, could you [edit] your question and make it clear exactly what filesystem you've used on the two USB sticks.

Comment: I tried with bote file system. First i tried with FAT32 and in next attempt i tried with NTFS that's what I want to say.

Comment: So are you saying it worked with FAT32 but not with NTFS?

Comment: I tried with bith file system first the observed USB-B is not working and in next try i copied default folders of Android os those are usually gets created to storage location to the both USB's then the scenario gets reverse means USB-B worked fine.